# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, code-signing

I know this has been asked before.

However, I have ensured that the profile is in BOTH the project and target.

Actually should I set that up in the project or in target?

[image]

Update: I can actually install the app on device but if and only if I change the code signing identity to iPhone Developer for debug.

However, I obviously want to launch the application with my distribution profile instead of my developer profile.

Comment: From the looks of your screen shot and your error its asking you to code sign the "any SDK" Have you tried changing that?

Comment: The way I did it is I deleted all certificate, etc. And then I re download everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this thing solved.

Basically I deleted all certificate and provisioning profile from itunes connect or apple developer website.

Then I waited 5 minutes. Add 2 distribution provisioning profile. Then do it again.

It works.

Oh ya, I need to ensure that the code signing identity points to the right provisioning profile. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your deployment target less than 6.1. It will work

Comment: How does that work? Code signing errors/requirements are nothing to do with iOS versions

Comment: I made my certificates and profiles and download them from developer.apple.com today, in the stage of the adding the device I set only one iOS 6.1.3 device but I need to build to iOS 5.x as lower version. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: set deployment target to 5.x

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I didn't set the Scheme correctly. Newbies can forget this sometimes.

Go to: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Select `Archive` and make sure that the `Build Configuration` has desired value Debug/Release (as compared to target settings)