# xcode 5.0.2: code signing operation failed check that the identity you selected is valid

Tags: ios5, ios7, xcode5, ipa

it has been asked alot of times, and i tried all the green mark solutions, nothing helped.

i want to get an ipa file of my project, and i keep getting this error i mentioned at the top.

i tried to delete all the certificates + all my apps id's + devices id's + proviosioning profiles,

basically i've cleaned up all of my developer details from apple developer portal, and than create

everything, clean and built the project, but again, i keep getting this error.

and it happens only in this specific app, in my other apps everything works fine and i can get the

ipa files.

tried this - [Codesign error: Provisioning profile cannot be found after deleting expired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof/1760738#1760738)

and that - [CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262177/codesign-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk)

and ofcourse checked that my bundle identifier in my project is the same as the AppID in the portal.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

apparently there is a problem in the filename.xcodeproj file when trying to edit a project which was

built on xcode 4, in xcode 5.0.2.

so i took the previous version of this file, and replaced it in the new and edited project, and now it's

working and i can get my ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, it could also be due to some problematic javscript files

> Gruntfile.js, karma-e2e.conf.js, karma.conf.js, and the entire node_modules directory.

see: [How to build IPA for distribution with TestFlight with XCode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109616/1449799)