# code signing operation failed check that the identity you selected is valid

Tags: ios, xcode5, ipa, signing, operation

I am writing an Interactive book application(TheBlueJackal.xcodeProj).when I run the application it is working fine but when I tried to create .ipa (IPA file) and when I click on export button after selecting the corresponding provisioning profile I am getting the following error

Code signing operation failed
Check that the identity you selected is valid.

I want to know when this error occur. I tried a lot in google but unable to find the correct reason. Can anyone please help me in understanding this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9649804/1062286

Comment: Bundle identifier of provisioning profile should match it in Info->Bundle identifier.

Comment: the below link solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431873/xcode-5-0-2-code-signing-operation-failed-check-that-the-identity-you-selected